# Can I use axios in this example?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm still new to web development so I'm really sorry if the answer is obvious or the information provided by me is not much, but I hope this is sufficient:

Can I make an **axios.post** request within this vue.js component?

```js
<script>

module.exports = {
  mounted() {
  
  // game code
  
  };

</script>
```

Let me explain the problem I'm having at this moment: I can't import axios by `import axios from "axios";`. I neither can use `export default { ... }`. Both result in the page not loading (giving me an *TypeError: "exports" is read-only*). However, I need to access a variable within the gamecode since I want to axios.post that said variable  (game score plus some more json info) to my MongoDB database.

If I can't make the request from there, am I able to get a variable from that code in `mounted() { // game code };` and pass it to another component (and post it from there)? I searched the Internet for many hours but nothing seems to work for me, so again, sorry if it seems like I'm just too lazy to search for answers.

Comment: Are you using `vue-cli`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use axios within the module.exports part of the code.
Normally I would use `import axios from 'axios';` and use axios as a method within

```
export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        // here (axios method)
        ...
```

But the

```
module.exports = { mounted() {
     // game code
     };
```

part did not work if I used the `export default` code part. I'm almost sure there is a more elegant way to solve this whole problem, but since I'm new and still don't understand totally how Vue and axios works, I simply tried some possibilities to include axios there and one worked:

```
module.exports = { mounted() {
     const axios = require("axios");
     // game code
     // and later, for example: axios.post(...)...
     };
```

At first I thought it wouldn't work since my IDE did not recognize the axios methods, but it actually posted data to my DB, so it did work.